# Customising Incollection author and editor fields

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

My publisher wants me to have all the editor and author fields in plain text, but actually I got them in smallcaps for the Incollections.
How could I fix the issue?

MWE:

```
% !BIB TS-program = biber
% !BIB program = biber
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TeX TS-program = xelatexmk

\begin{filecontents}{archivio.bib}


@incollection{Sch:Pho,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {Jacques Schamp},
    Booktitle = {Dictionnaire des Philosophes Antiques},
    Editor = {Richard Goulet},
    Langid = {french},
    Publisher = {\textsc{cnrs}},
    Title = {Photios},
    Year = {2012}}

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[11pt, openany]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{italian}
\setotherlanguages{latin, english, french}

\usepackage[]{csquotes}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[style=verbose-trad2,
            language=auto,
            ibidpage=true,
            autolang=other,% use new option name
            useprefix=true,
            giveninits=true,
            indexing=true,% or cite?
            citepages=separate,%
            dateabbrev=false,
            backend=biber,
        ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Archivio.bib}   

\DeclareFieldFormat[article, inbook, incollection, inproceedings]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[book, inbook, incollection, inproceedings]{volume}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article, inbook, incollection, inproceedings]{citetitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}}

\begin{document}

\textit{Incollection:}\\
\cite[]{Sch:Pho}\\

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: This results from your use of `langid={french}` for your bibentry and `autolang=other`. Small caps is a setting for the french language in biblatex, not for `incollection`. Would you like this changed for this particular entry, for french overall, or to not use `autolang=other`?

Comment: I need the language specification for other custom settings, but I want all author and editor names to be printed in normal plain text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The small caps in your example does not emerge because this is an `incollection` entry, but rather because that particular entry has `langid={french}` and you use `autolang=other` as a biblatex setting. And `french.lbx` is set to typeset family names in small caps. As you want to keep the language specification, you should redefine this for `french` with:

```
\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{%
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textnohyphenation{#1}}%
}
```

In full:

```
% !BIB TS-program = biber
% !BIB program = biber
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TeX TS-program = xelatexmk

\begin{filecontents}{archivio.bib}


@incollection{Sch:Pho,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {Jacques Schamp},
    Booktitle = {Dictionnaire des Philosophes Antiques},
    Editor = {Richard Goulet},
    Langid = {french},
    Publisher = {\textsc{cnrs}},
    Title = {Photios},
    Year = {2012}}

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[11pt, openany]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{italian}
\setotherlanguages{latin, english, french}


\usepackage[]{csquotes}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[style=verbose-trad2,
            language=auto,
            ibidpage=true,
            autolang=other,% use new option name
            useprefix=true,
            giveninits=true,
            indexing=true,% or cite?
            citepages=separate,%
            dateabbrev=false,
            backend=biber,
            ]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{%
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textnohyphenation{#1}}%
}

\addbibresource{Archivio.bib}   

\DeclareFieldFormat[article, inbook, incollection, inproceedings]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[book, inbook, incollection, inproceedings]{volume}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article, inbook, incollection, inproceedings]{citetitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}}

\begin{document}

\textit{langid={french}:}\\
\cite[]{Sch:Pho}\\

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Slightly shorter, but without the `\textnohyphenation` would be `\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\restorecommand\mkbibnamefamily}`.

Comment: @moewe, that's for the insiders who noticed the command was even saved in the first place.